# Insert DateTime into Database

Tags: asp.net, sql, datetime

I have a DateTime field in my SQL database which I want to write a time to, but how do I do this?

I'm wanting to do it as a timestamp, so when the user clicks an "add" button it adds the data to the other fields, and a timestamp into the DateTime field, but I keep getting the following error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

This is my current code in the CS file

```
insertSQL = "INSERT INTO Posts (TopicID, PostBody, PostDate, UserID)"
        + "VALUES ('" + topic + "', '" + newPostText + "', '" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "', '" + User_ID + "')";
```

Please note I'm wanting to display as much time info as I can. Eg 23/05/2012 10:58:00 a.m.

Comment: In the SQL Server, set the "Default Value or binding" to (getdate()) for smalldatetime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your implementation is prone to `SQL Injection`. To resolve that, AND your DateTime issue, use parameters - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx

Something like this:

```
string commandText = "INSERT INTO Posts (TopicID, PostBody, PostDate, UserID)"
    + "VALUES (@Topic, @NewPostText, @PostDate, @UserID)";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Topic", "My Topic");
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewPostText", "Post text goes here");
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostDate", dateObject);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", "UserA");

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        Int32 rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // Handle Errors    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I know it's prone currently, but that didn't answer my question

Comment: Using parameters _is_ the answer to your issue. Parameters can preserve data types, so instead of injecting the DateTime into the SQL as a string and forcing SQL to try and convert it back into a DateTime, the SQL engine will receive a DateTime object.

Comment: +1 for changing from a poor link answer to a real answer with a link as a reference

Comment: Ah I understand now. Sorry. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Are you asking for strtotime()  ?

```
<?php
$d = date('y-m-d');
echo date('d M Y',strtotime( $d ));
echo "<br>";
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>
```

sigh, my fault, it's for Php~

Comment: :). Thanks for giving a go though

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with asp.net ^_^ Good luck.

Comment: -1: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, you have not answered the question. When answering a question about an asp.net problem, the solution is likely going to involve asp.net, not php. And when answering a question about inserting a value into a database, the correct answer will likely demonstrate inserting a value into a database, not just formatting it. Look at @Snixtor's answer to see how you might improve upon your solution.

Comment: Actually, I don't think it's necessary~ When looking for a solution, we only need a hint, but not complete solution.